# Minimalist Ubuntu without the default window manager

Tags: server, system-installation, window-manager

I'm about to install Linux on my new laptop (Dell XPS15 9550), but I usually end up with a bloated installation because I like to use the i3 window manager. This means I have GNOME etc installed but rarely if ever used.

Is it worth installing the server version of Ubuntu then just `aptitude install i3wm` and so-on, or will the hardware compatibility & convenience of the desktop edition still be a long way off?

Alternatively, is there a mature, secure Ubuntu (or Debian) derivative that will satisfy my installation requirements?

Comment: No official Ubuntu flavour comes with i3 pre-installed. As for hardware compatibility, the server edition uses the exact same kernel. Only you can say if it is "worth" it, we can't judge for you.

Comment: Install a minimal Ubuntu, plus enough development packages for you to be able to compile i3 yourself.